# How to use a variable in a command that's creating another variable

Tags: linux, bash, variables

I created my basic variable from a read command (I've done this manually and using a script):

```
read NAME
```

I then want to use that `NAME` variable to search a file and create another variable:

```
STUDENT=$(grep $NAME <students.dat | awk -F: '/$NAME/ {print $1}')
```

If I run the command manually with an actual name from that students.dat file (and not $NAME), it executes and displays what I want. However, when I run this command (manually or from the script using `$NAME`), it returns blank, and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shell variables aren't interpolated in single quotes, only double quotes.

```
STUDENT=$(grep $NAME <students.dat | awk -F: "/$NAME/ {print \$1}")
```

`$1` needs to be escaped to ensure it's not expanded by the shell, but by awk.

Comment: Passing the value of `$NAME` with the `-v` option is safer.

Comment: Beautiful! That did it. Thanks!

Comment: It's better to enclose $NAME in double quotes while passing to `grep`.  Also, use `--` to prevent failures caused by any leading `-` in $NAME.  So, `grep -- "$NAME"` is much better.

Answer (score 2):

@user1615415: Try:

```
cat script.ksh
echo "Enter name.."
read NAME
STUDENT=$(awk -vname="$NAME" -F: '($0 ~ name){print $3}' student.dat)
```